# Bad Operand types for binary operator && when trying to calculate birthdate from current date

Tags: java, date, operators, logical-and

I am trying to get a user to input YR MON DAY and then system calculate the current age based on the provided input and show the age on the screen.

Here is the beginning to my code:

```
static void checkAgeFormat(int current_date, int current_month,
                            int current_year, int birth_date,
                            int birth_month, int birth_year) {
    int f = 0;
    if(current_date <= 01 && current_date => 31) {
        System.out.println("Invalid current_date");
        f = 1;
    }
```

I am getting a *"Bad Operand types for binary operator &&"* I cannot figure out why, and I am fairly new to coding.
Thanks for any help

Comment: `=>` is an incorrect operator. It should be `>=`. Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html to learn more about operators.

Comment: BTW `current_date <= 1 && current_date >= 31` cannot both be true at the same time, so you will never get into the inner part of your `if` statement. You might have intended `current_date < 1 || current_date > 31`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is `>=` not `=>` so  `if(current_date<=1 && current_date>=31)`

(don't use 0 as prefix for numbers, it causes them to be interpreted as octal)

Comment: Thank you for the information, what should I use then?

Comment: @JosiahReyes >=

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to return here? The amount of days left before someones birthdate? You could use the `between()` method of `Period` class for that.

```
static void checkAgeFormat(int current_date, int current_month,
                            int current_year, int birth_date,
                            int birth_month, int birth_year) {
LocalDate birthDate = LocalDate.of(birth_year, birth_month, birth_date);
long daysLeft = Period.between(LocalDate.now(), birthDate).get(ChronoUnit.DAYS);


}
```

Comment: I am trying to get a user to input YR MON DAY and then system calculate the current age based on the provided input and show the age on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

As I have already mentioned in the comment, the issue is because of the bad symbol, `=>` for the operator. It should be `>=`. Check [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) to learn more about operators.

Apart from that, I can see a serious problem with your logic. The way you are validating the date values is a naive way to do it. I suggest you do it using OOTB APIs as shown below:

```
import java.time.DateTimeException;
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Tests
        checkAgeFormat(45, 10, 2017, 10, 10, 2010);
        checkAgeFormat(30, 2, 2017, 10, 10, 2010);
        checkAgeFormat(31, 4, 2017, 10, 10, 2010);
        checkAgeFormat(30, 15, 2017, 10, 10, 2010);
        checkAgeFormat(30, 4, 2020, 10, 10, 2010);
    }

    static void checkAgeFormat(int current_day, int current_month, int current_year, int birth_day, int birth_month,
            int birth_year) {
        int f = 0;
        LocalDate currentDate, birthDate;
        try {
            currentDate = LocalDate.of(current_year, current_month, current_day);
            birthDate = LocalDate.of(birth_year, birth_month, birth_day);
            System.out.println("If you see this line printed, the date values are correct.");
            // ...Rest of the code
        } catch (DateTimeException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            f = 1;
        }
        // ...Rest of code
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
Invalid value for DayOfMonth (valid values 1 - 28/31): 45
Invalid date 'FEBRUARY 30'
Invalid date 'APRIL 31'
Invalid value for MonthOfYear (valid values 1 - 12): 15
If you see this line printed, the date values are correct.
```

Answer (score 0):

isn't it easier to write a function where the user will provide year, month and the day and it will return how old is the user? Below is an example of a function that does it.

```
public static int getYears(int year, int month, int day)
{
    LocalDate yearOfBirth = LocalDate.of(year, month, day);
    LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();
    Period period = Period.between(yearOfBirth, currentDate);
    return period.getYears();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you are getting the error because

you are using `if (current_date <= 01 && current_date =>31)` instead of

```
if (current_date <= 01 && current_date >=31)
```

after editing your code will be:

```
static void checkAgeFormat(int current_date, int current_month, int current_year, int birth_date, int birth_month, int birth_year) {

        int f=0
        if (current_date <= 01 && current_date >=31){
            System.out.println("Invalid current_date");
            f=1;
        }
}
```

Comment: @whoever Why the downvote, please? I can’t see that this answer is any worse than the others (only 5 answers seem to be more than needed for a simple typo).